# Strange special character/Latin characters

Tags: php, apache, encoding, linux

We have developed many blogs on wordpress which is hosted on Rackspace server(Red Hat). Last Sunday we worked on user and set 'myuser' to run as PHP. So if we execute

`echo shell_exec('whoami');` then the result will be **'myuser'**.

Before this, the PHP is running as **apache** user. So now we changed this to **'myuser'**

**Only after this changes, A lot of apostrophes and a some characters or letters have converted.**

My MySQL and WordPress charset are unchanged. **So everything were just perfect before the above mentioned changes.**

And now I am fixing this by going through each and every posts manually.

What could be the problem? And how we can fix this?

Please see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Still no idea that why and how this happened all of sudden. But here is the 2 Solutions I found which is working: Applying anyone will work

`1. Comment these two - //define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8') and //define('DB_COLLATE', '')
 2. Use Latin1, ('DB_CHARSET', 'latin1')`

However, I am suspecting some attacks on our sever where blogs are hosted and investigating into this.